# Boolean return type not working with RestTemplate

Tags: spring, apache-servicemix

I am using Spring 3.0.3 RestTemplate for making RESTfull call to service which is deployed in servicemix ESB. Service method returns boolean value, and am unable to receive this in RestTemplate response.

```
String query = "?userId="+userId;
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

boolean status = rest.getForObject(SERVICE_URL+query,boolean.class,params);
```

And am getting below error

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - GET request for "http://localhost:818 1/cxf/monitoring/logclear?userId=admin" resulted in 406 (Not Acceptable); invoking error handler org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 406 Not Acceptable at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultR esponseErrorHandler.java:69) at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:486)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:206)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: boolean is a primative type, not a class.  Have you tried returning Boolean (a class)?

Comment: Yes, I have tried but no luck